# Magento Cart: Thumbnail Images Don't Appear in Chrome or Safari

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, image, thumbnail

I'm unable to see my product thumbnails on the cart page when I use Chrome or Safari. They do however appear in Firefox. The line rendering these images is in app/design/frontend/my_package/my_theme/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

```
<td><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image"><?php endif;?><img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(75,75); ?>" width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" /><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?></a><?php endif;?></td>
```

Despite being sized at 75px X 75px, the image is rendered in the browser at 0px X 75px, making it invisible. Inspecting the code shows that it is indeed there, it's just the wrong size. My first thought was an issue with class="product-image", but removing the class didn't change the output.

[image]

I've also tried a couple different ways of pulling up the image, all of which give the exact same result - a 0px X 75px image:

```
$_product = $_item->getProduct();
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image') ?>" width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" />
```

Any ideas what might solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide your site URL?

Comment: jibsactionsports.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its css issue

You just need to give width to the "th" of the image "td".
JUST ADD IT IN YOUR CSS WITH PROPER FORMATION 
LIKE:

```
table#shopping-cart-table > thead > tr > th:first-child {
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

check screenshot [image]

Answer (score 1):

Add this `CSS`

```
table#shopping-cart-table > thead > tr > th:first-child {
    min-width: 96px;
}
```

I don't know the exact issue. But we can fix this issue by the above style.